# How do I get percentage accuracy test of regression with negative values?

Tags: python

I am evaluating my outputs and currently am using RMSE and R², I also want to include an accuracy measurement in %. However, Ive read that MAPE cant be used on negative data and I am getting strange results.

```
mape = np.mean(np.abs((y_test - y_pred6)/y_test))*100
mape

168.9513754915605
```

RMSE is at 5000$ (real value) with the values ranging between -15k and 40k.

Is there a metric that allows accuracy measurement for negative (and psitive) outputs in %?
Is it even necessary as the ranks for the metrics correlate, highest R² has lowest RMSE.

Comment: MAPE is problematic for zero values, not negative values. Please explain the strange point for your result.

Comment: Okay. Thats what I read on my research, thanks for correcting me. With strange I mean that the MAPE should be between 0 and 100 if I understood it right. But I have a value of 168, which doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: There is no strange thing. If the true value is 10 and measured (or predicted, ...) value is 30, absolute percentage error is 200%. MAPE is just an average of absolute percentage errors.

Comment: Okay, that definetly makes sense. So following that argumentation, my prediction is in average 68% higher than the true value, so I could say I have an inaccuracy of 68% or in other words an accurracy of 32%?
Ive found a lot of papers where metrics are just listed for comparison, but I actually want to interpret my results

Comment: Definitely not. Why 168% become 68%? I would like to recommend you to first study basic statistics instead of research papers.